# Rsepc - Database cleaner with Neo4j.rb 8.0.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j.rb, database-cleaner

With Old version of neo4j & eno4j.rb everything was working good

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    DatabaseCleaner[:neo4j, connection: { type: :server_db, path: ENV['TEST_GRAPHENEDB_URL'] }].strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner[:neo4j, connection: { type: :server_db, path: ENV['TEST_GRAPHENEDB_URL'] }].strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner[:neo4j, connection: { type: :server_db, path: ENV['TEST_GRAPHENEDB_URL'] }].strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    DatabaseCleaner[:neo4j, connection: { type: :server_db, path: ENV['TEST_GRAPHENEDB_URL'] }].start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    DatabaseCleaner[:neo4j, connection: { type: :server_db, path: ENV['TEST_GRAPHENEDB_URL'] }].clean
  end
end
```

After Upgrade with a new version of Neo4j & Neo4j.rb I have changed this file

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    Neo4j::ActiveBase.current_session.query('MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n')
  end
end
```

This is my database cleaner file , I am using postgres & neo4j in my project I have done this after looking at 
`http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/Miscellany.html#cleaning-your-database-for-testing` I am getting issue when I run test cases

```
 Neo4j::PendingMigrationError:
   Migrations are pending:
   20170324201940
   20170324202013
   20170324202025
   20170324202040
   20170324202053
   20170324202110
   20170324202522
   20170324202604
   20170324202801
   20170328203203
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest just getting rid of `DatabaseCleaner` entirely.  It offers three different forms of database cleaning, but only one really works with Neo4j so there isn't much point (see [this page](http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/Miscellany.html#cleaning-your-database-for-testing)).

You should be able to do `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n` if you are using 8.1.x of the `neo4j` gem.  Previously if you deleted the whole database the gem would complain that migrations need to be run because the `SchemaMigration` nodes would have been deleted.  In 8.1, that check is now ignored.  Before 8.1 you'd want to do something like:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE NOT n:`Neo4j::Migrations::SchemaMigration` DETACH DELETE n
```

Also, separately, in 8.1 you may want to not do `rake neo4j:migrate` and instead do `rake neo4j:schema:load` which loads all of the constraints / indexes instead of running through each migration, which can get slower and slower as you get more migrations.  For `neo4j:schema:load` to work, though, you need to make sure that the `db/neo4j/schema.yml` file is checked into your repository (that file is re-generated fresh every time you run `rake neo4j:migrate` so that it's in sync with your migrations)

I also prefer putting my `DELETE` statement in a `before(:each)` rather than an `after(:each)` so that I can be sure that my tests are running in a fresh state.  Otherwise one broken test file which *doesn't* clean up after itself messes up another test file and it's generally not clear what's going on when that happens.